# Meaning of "in your general direction"

Tags: meaning, phrases

I'm not a native English speaker, and I don't understand the meaning of the phrase "in your general direction."

I have found its use in the line from *Monty Python and the Holy Grail*:

> I fart in your general direction.

Comment: What is the question?  Fart is funny in many parts of the world. If you are in doubt, give it a google search.

Comment: okay ignore why it's funny question. What does "in your general direction" mean exactly.. ( I assumed it means "toward about where you are standing" )

Comment: @Noah, What confuses me is the "in one's general direction" part. I come across, "Eight threw profanity in my general direction." After read this question, I think I understand it somehow. But I still don't know why it uses "general."

Answer (score 3):

You hit the nail on the head -- it means "toward about where you are standing".

Comment: Sorry Cornbread, the OP updated the question in the comments to one that's worth answering. I've edited the question to be about what he's interested in.

Comment: @MattЭллен updated FWIW.  :)

Comment: Thanks!! that's what I thought it meant.. but then, The movie actually made me confused.... I couldn't get why it's supposed be so funny..and thought maybe 'in your general direction" had more meaning inside..

Comment: @megaboy no more meaning. it's just a silly way of saying "at you".  No one really talks like that.

Answer (score 3):

I am guessing it is the 'general' causing problems?

It just means that the fart is not aimed precisely at the victim, like a gunshot, but more or less in his direction in more of an "over there somewhere" sort of way.

Comment: hanks!! that's what I thought it meant.. but then, The movie actually made me confused.... I couldn't get why it's supposed be so funny..and thought maybe 'in your general direction" had more meaning inside...